# Get current page id, title, url, etc

Tags: variables, globals

Sorry but I get lost on Wordpress's codex.
I am trying to add a mail this page sharing link and want to include some info from the page.
In pseudo code is this possible?

`<a href="mailto:?subject=".CURRENT_BLOG_NAME." ".CURRENT_PAGE_TITLE."&amp;body="intro%20text%20".WP_PLUGIN_URL.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].">Mail to a friend</a>`

Where `CURRENT_BLOG_NAME` is ???
and `CURRENT_PAGE_TITLE` is ???

`WP_PLUGIN_URL.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` **does** get me the path to the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$link = 'mailto:?subject='. get_bloginfo() .' '. the_title_attribute(array('echo'=>0));
$link .= '&amp;body=some text '. get_permalink();
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>">mail to a friend</a>
```

Comment: I think this is the long way but it works also 'http%3A%2F%2F'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function for such things.

Furthermore there's a function called [`get_permalink();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink). And another one called [`get_the_title();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

You can combine them in a function:

```
function wpse25552_mail_permalink()
{
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $subject = sprintf( __('I want to share %1$s with you', YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN ), $title );

    $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $message = sprintf( __("Yo! Look what I've found here: %1$s", YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN), $permalink );

    // ... stuff for $to, $subject, etc.

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
}
```

*Note, that you have to replace `YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN` with your themes textdomain string. Else you can leave it out (don't forget to delete the comma too).*